# Do something on placeholder applied to Glide?

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide, placeholder

Can I know if there is any method that I can use to do something when **loading** **placeholder** to the **Glide**. Here I have set a `firebase` image url to `setBitmap` method using `Glide`. if resource available `setBitmap` method will run. If it is not available I want to run a another method. Is there a method something like `onLoadingPlaceholder()`?

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap()
                            .load(dataSnapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue(String.class))
                            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.image)
                                    .error(R.drawable.image))
                            .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onResourceReady: ");
                                    setBitmap(resource);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {}
                            });
```

Simply What I need to do is that, set a bitmap when placeholder load. So I need to set a default image when `firebase` image is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer. But it is not something like `onLoadPlaceholder()`, This works for me!

```
String imageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue(String.class);
if(imageUrl==null){
    setBitmap(resource);
}

Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap()
        .load(imageUrl)
        .apply(new RequestOptions()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.contatctmani)
                .error(R.drawable.contatctmani))
        .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                setBitmap(resource);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {}
        });
```

Comment: Sorry haven't notices the `asBitmap()`. And yes in that case the placeholders won't work. Thx for sharing your solution with use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fallback` like here:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .fallback(R.drawable.fallback)
  .into(view);
```

It will be shown if `url` is `null`.

And just in case the `error` handler:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .error(R.drawable.error)
  .into(view);
```

Comment: thanks, but how can i run my setBitmap() ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
            @Override
            public void onLoadStarted(@NonNull placeholder Drawable) {
               // here you call another method, e.g.
               imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadFailed(@NonNull errorDrawable: Drawable) {
               // here you call another method, e.g.
               imageView.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable);
            }
```

into your into block.